# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError on Spring-Tiles integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

Getting following exception (I've Tiles 3.0.5+Spring4 integration)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.evaluate(BasicTilesContainer.java:267)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:253)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
```

Tiles Definitions

```
  <definition name="DefaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/SiteTemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header"    value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu"      value="" />
    <put-attribute name="body"      value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer"    value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="tree" extends="DefaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="menu"  value="/WEB-INF/jsp/Tree.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="error" extends="DefaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body"  value="/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu"  value="" />
</definition>

<definition name="login" extends="DefaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body"  value="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu"  value="" />
</definition>
```

I get the exception in using any of these tiles definitions through a Spring-controller.

Comment: can you list what dependencies you have on the classpath? if using maven `mvn dependency:tree` will list it out.

Comment: I'm not using maven. Here, I'm pasting classpath dependencies - tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.1.0.jar, spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, tiles-api-3.0.5.jar, tiles-compat-3.0.5.jar, tiles-core-3.0.5.jar, tiles-el-3.0.5.jar, tiles-extras-3.0.5.jar, tiles-jsp-3.0.5.jar, tiles-request-api-1.0.6.jar, tiles-request-jsp-1.0.6.jar, tiles-request-servlet-1.0.6.jar, tiles-servlet-3.0.5.jar

Comment: have you a chance to test against a newer spring version?

Comment: @mck - I am already using the latest version of spring (4). I could resolve this issue by adding more tiles related dependent jars. The weird thing was that this exception wasn't coming on every dev setup. On other dev setups, its working even without adding more tiles jars.

Comment: that is odd. while it sounds like a build issue rather than anything specific to tiles if you do find it out feel free to post it to the tiles user list.